# Get foreign key value without join In Entity-to-Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

`Employee` table has `Departmentid` foreign key with a relation to the `Department` table's `Id` column.

Now if I select all rows from the `Employee` table, I should get the department name for their respective `DepartmentId` in the foreign key column of `Employee` table.

I'm using Entity Framework I can do thing using join via creating another object of `Department` table.

Output should be like:

```
EmployeeName    EmployeeAddress  EmployeeDepartment
    abc            xyz                  IT
```

It should automatically fetch foreign key value for `Employee`

```
lamiEntities1 lam = new lamiEntities1();
        var query =( from sls in lam.sales.AsEnumerable() join it in lam.items on sls.ItemId equals it.Id orderby sls.Id descending
                    select new

                    {
                        ItemName = it.ItemName,
                        TotalAmounts = sls.Amount,
                        Remarks=sls.Remarks,
                        Dates = sls.Date

                    }).Take(20);

        GridView1.DataSource = query;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Here how can i remove join and use directly itemname using itemid forign key

Comment: I guess you mean without **explicit** join in your query. Use **navigation properties** and EF will do that for you.

Comment: Yes I dont want to join and make another object and match Two property.

If i'm using Foreign Key relation the it should automatically fetch its values

Comment: What is your actual question? Can you please provide some code and describe the question in more detail?

Comment: Automatically get Foreign key value without using join , using Linq-Entity Query ?
There is nothing fancy in my question please read text

Comment: Your question and the code don't match. I'd recommend you do some reading on [Entity Framework associations mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx).

Comment: I got the Answer See Pedro's post below, Ned some clarification that's why i Did not mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you looking for:

You can make a DTO(Data Transfer Object), to transport the data between the layers

```
public class EmployeeWithDepartmentDto
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeAddress { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

And you get the results like this:

```
var result = employeeRepository.Select(e => new EmployeeWithDepartmentDto { EmployeeName = e.Name, EmployeeAddress = e.Address, DepartmentName = e.Department.Name });

foreach (var employeeWithDepartmentDto in result)
     Console.WriteLine($"Name: {employeeWithDepartmentDto.EmployeeName}, Address: {employeeWithDepartmentDto.EmployeeAddress}, Department: {employeeWithDepartmentDto.DepartmentName}");
```

[Here is an example in DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FKYvUp)

If you dont wanna create a DTO class, you can make the query using anonymous objects

```
var result = employeeRepository.Select(e => new { EmployeeName = e.Name, EmployeeAddress = e.Address, DepartmentName = e.Department.Name });
```

Or you can query like this, using Linq-To-Sql:

```
var result = from e in employeeRepository
                select new EmployeeWithDepartmentDto
                {
                    EmployeeName = e.Name,
                    EmployeeAddress = e.Address,
                    DepartmentName = e.Department.Name
                }
```

If you are using EF with [Eager Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx), you must use Include, this way:

```
lamiEntities1 lam = new lamiEntities1();
    var query =( from sls in lam.sales.Include("item")
                orderby sls.Id descending
                select new

                {
                    ItemName = sls.Item.ItemName,
                    TotalAmounts = sls.Amount,
                    Remarks=sls.Remarks,
                    Dates = sls.Date

                }).Take(20);
```

Comment: How will we do using Linq Query ,

Comment: Could you please take a look at my update @Pedro

Comment: You're missing the mark. The question is exactly about the things you don't explain: how to get navigation properties like `sls.Item.ItemName` working. As an aside, the `Include` in your last code fragment has no effect.

Comment: Thank you so much For Your Reply yes it works, but could you please explain what you did. how these things are working.

Comment: @Akash You dont need to explicit make a join between your tables,  when you have Navigation Properties into each entity, because EF will make the work for you, and this is what i did. Im using linq-to-sql and acessing the navigation property directly.

Comment: Thanks for your time , By This Line "sls in lam.sales.Include("item")" 
what i understand is sls object having sales table properties as well as referencing  to Item table's property at line " ItemName = sls.Item.ItemName,"

am i getting it right ?

Comment: @Akash thats right, the Include() is to explicit load the object into Navigation Properties, i've put a link into the answer that explain about Eager Loading, you should read it. After i call this Include, i can access all properties into the sls.Item property.

Comment: @Akash could you please mark my answer as the correct one?

Comment: Again I need you bro , What if i need to refer more than one foreign key example-: Now i Have PartyId foreign key referes to party name how would you include more than one tabel?

Comment: @Akash I did not understand, could you tell me more about this ?

Comment: @Pedro I resolved The Issue Thanks For your time and concern 

This is what i was asking "from sl   lam.sales.Include("item").Include("Stock") "  here i'm referencing two tables .